# USB-Tethering not working on Ubuntu 20.04, no network devices available

Tags: usb, android, tethering, kubuntu-netbook

No USB tethering device available.
Smartphone: Android One (full updated)
System Kubuntu 20.04

When I connect the smartphone via USB to my laptop, I select "USB tethering", but the device is not displayed in Kubuntu. Connecting to the HotSpot via WiFi works.

```
ip link show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp3s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp4s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```